# ListLinearLogPlot doesn't work

Tags: plotting

So I'm trying to plot my data using ListLinearLogPlot.

```
data1 = Import["Path to my file with data", 
"Table"][[All, {2, 1}]]; 
ListLinearLogPlot[data1,PlotRange -> Full]
```

When I try to plot LogLinear it does work perfectly. If I try to plot this I just get list of points and the output is:

```
 ListLinearLogPlot[{{0.1, 0.997253}, {0.1, 0.994505}, {0.1,
```

and so on. How can I fix this and get my plot?

Comment: It's either `ListLogPlot` or `ListLogLinearPlot`.

Comment: ... Or `ListLogLogPlot`. Those are the three options.

Comment: Have a look [Some Special Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeSpecialPlots.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are four existing functions: ListPlot, ListLogPlot, ListLogLinearPlot and ListLogLogPlot. There is no such ListLinearLogPlot. So Mathematica considers it as an undefined function.